# What framework is "_DieWithError", referenced from?

Tags: c, linker-errors

I am compiling code from TCP/IP Sockets in C by Donahoo using Xcode 5.0. The code can be found here: http://cs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/practical/CSockets/code/UDPEchoServer.c

On compile I get error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_DieWithError", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What framework is "_DieWithError", referenced from? I can't seem to find that on the internet.

Comment: I don't know but given it's name and usage you could probably roll your own without too much trouble.

Comment: google it: http://cs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/practical/CSockets/code/DieWithError.c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@CharlieBurns comment contains the answer. I misunderstood Donahoo in his book, "_DieWithError" is an external error handling function written for the book (it's not in any of apple's frameworks). So if you encounter the same problem and you've found this page try putting the file from @CharlieBurns comment in your source directory. The link wont post here because it's not allowed by stackoverflow (incidentally if you know why that is please comment?).